# Symfony configuration validation of keys in key-value pairs in prototype node

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, symfony-2.8

In Symfony 2.8, given this YAML config block

```
my_bundle:
  profiles:
    'abc': 123
    'def: 456
    '...': ...
```

How can I validate the keys in the key-values under profiles are non-empty string?

In this case 'abc' and 'def' are just examples, these are arbitrary, they cannot be pre-defined.

Here's my Configuration file -

```
->arrayNode('profiles')
    ->isRequired()
    ->requiresAtLeastOneElement()
    ->useAttributeAsKey('name')
    ->prototype('integer')
        ->min(0)
    ->end()
->end()
```

The problem is

```
my_bundle:
  profiles:
    123
    456
```

is valid when I don't want it to be.

I could not find an easy in-built way to validate keys of prototype arrays.

**Possible solutions**

**One:** Seems that I *could* make it an array of arrays

```
my_bundle:
  profiles:
    -
      name: abc
      value: 123
    -
      name: def
      value: 456
```

with

```
->arrayNode('profiles')
    ->isRequired()
    ->useAttributeAsKey('name')
    ->requiresAtLeastOneElement()
    ->prototype('array')
        ->children()
            ->scalarNode('name')
                ->isRequired()
                ->cannotBeEmpty()
                ->validate()
                    ->ifTrue(
                        function($s) {
                            return !is_string($s);
                        }
                    )
                    ->thenInvalid('Profile key must be a non-empty string')
                ->end()
            ->end()
            ->integerNode('value')
                ->isRequired()
                ->min(0)
            ->end()
        ->end()
    ->end()
```

but I'd prefer not to do that as our customers already have the original format in their config, we can more easily update the Configuration than the config files themselves.

**Two:** Seems that I *could* do #1 without changing the config by adding some normalisation to convert the old config format to a new format first

```
->arrayNode('profiles')
    ->beforeNormalization()
        ->ifTrue(
            function($array) {
                $hasSimpleKeyValuePair = false;
                foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
                    if (!is_array($value)) {
                        $hasSimpleKeyValuePair = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                return $hasSimpleKeyValuePair;
            }
        )
        ->then(
            function($array) {
                $newArray = [];
                foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
                    if (!is_array($value)) {
                        $newArray[] = ['name' => $key, 'value' => $value];
                    }
                }
                return $newArray;
            }
        )
    ->end()
    ->isRequired()
    ->requiresAtLeastOneElement()
    ->prototype('array')
        ->children()
            ->scalarNode('name')
                ->isRequired()
                ->cannotBeEmpty()
                ->validate()
                    ->ifTrue(
                        function($s) {
                            return !is_string($s);
                        }
                    )
                    ->thenInvalid('Profile key must be a non-empty string')
                ->end()
            ->end()
            ->integerNode('value')
                ->isRequired()
                ->min(0)
            ->end()
        ->end()
    ->end()
->end()
```

but that seems like a massive overkill.

(These two options also mean I need to change the receivers of the profile data to know that rather than using the number, they need to use an array key index that points to the number, `$profile[$key]['value']` rather than just `$profile[$key]`, which I *can* do I guess)

**Three:** Seems that I *could* add a custom validation on the whole block

```
->arrayNode('profiles')
    ->isRequired()
    ->requiresAtLeastOneElement()
    ->useAttributeAsKey('name')
    ->prototype('integer')
        ->min(0)
    ->end()
    ->validate()
        ->ifTrue(function ($array) {
            $notValid = false;
            foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
                if (!is_string($key) || empty($key)) {
                    $notValid = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            return $notValid;
        })
        ->thenInvalid('Profile keys must be a non-empty string.')
    ->end()
->end()
```

which is what I'm going with for now, but still seems unnecessary custom/hacky for something I think would be a common use-case.

I just want to check I've not missed some magical in-built way to do this with Symfony configuration?